# "BTP ITALIA" Inflation Linker Pricing

Tags: option-pricing, inflation

I have some issue with pricing of Italian linker bonds (http://www.dt.tesoro.it/export/sites/sitodt/modules/documenti_en/debito_pubblico/titoli_di_stato/BTP_Italia.pdf) . The issue is their specific feature, I mean they have deflation floor not only at maturity but also on each coupon (semi-annual) that are based on a uplifted inflation notional plus the uplifted notional itself that is distributed to investors each semester with the coupon. How to handle this?

Could someone give me a hint (.xls formula/code) or a website where I can find code (python) for pricing this stream of floor options?

if other info are needed please ask me.

Comment: Could u post the link about the info of this product?

Comment: Is it this one ? http://www.dt.tesoro.it/export/sites/sitodt/modules/documenti_en/debito_pubblico/titoli_di_stato/BTP_Italia.pdf

Comment: Yes. The link you mention is correct
Thanks a lot

Comment: @jonny Please edit the link into your answer.

Comment: How about pricing each coupon like a Call option written on the inflation index?

Comment: @jansen what do you mean?

Comment: @lisa ann it could be. But then I add the premiuns of each ones to zero coupon bond ?

Comment: @jonny: yes, that's the way. Don't forget to take into account the possible spread over, that is, the nominal value of the coupon.

Comment: @lisa ann thank you! Have you, by chance,  strings of code

Comment: @lisa ann thank you! Have you, by chance, strings of code for this or libraries already available

Comment: @jonny: unfortunately no lines of code available but C++ and [QuantLib](https://www.quantlib.org/) may be your best friends ;)